# How to get Background color of text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wcag

currently i am working for digital accessibility
It is possible know background color lighter than text in jQuery
for example

```
<div style="background-color: red;" >
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/css/  `$("div").css("background-color")`

Comment: Getting the colour and checking it it's "lighter than text" are two very different issues.